# Pandas - Extracting based on key words

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract part of the text from a row using the below condition:

```
df['output'] = df['subject'].str.split('Class : ').str[1]
```

The above code works well, however if the row has multiple values of `Class` how could I modify this to extract the last one.

Example:

```
subject, output
Class Name : Science, Science
Class : Class Assigned Class : Math, Class Assigned Class : Math
```

How could I change the code to fix the output for the second row where the expected output is `Math` but since the word `Class` appears more than once it fetches from the first occurrence.

Comment: maybe,`split(': ')[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is pretty confusing because it doesn't really do what you're describing or what your example code does. The first line doesn't split at all because the splitting condition `"Class : "` never appears, and the second line splits differently than you're showing - it outputs `"Class Assigned"` in the element 1 of the list.

That said, just indexing with [-1] works fine for the second row to get just `Math`as an output.